# Could I use an existing angular 1 template with angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm trying to build a real-time reactive admin dashboard for an admin Dashboard/POS system. I'm mainly a Java developer who's also developed using .net. I've just started practing using MEAN stack to create real-time web apps, I wanted to buy a theme though so that I can spend more time working on the model/controller. I was gonna buy this theme for use:

https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/flatify-responsive-admin-web-app-WB0977873

I was originally planning on using Angular 1, however after doing more research i'm now learning towards angular 2 so that I can use Typescript. This theme doesn't explicitly say it works with angular 2, but would it still be possible to use? Would there be alot to convert?

Answer (score 0):

This theme is built with Angular 1.x. If you are planning for angular 2 then it will be of no use. Angular 2 is entirely at different level. For angular 2 you will need to use npm for installing dependencies and TypeScript compiler to compile typescript files.

Another thing is as Angular 2 is built on TypeScript of it uses decorators, interfaces, etc. that are not in angular 1.x. Angular 1.x was like ember and backbone but angular2 needed a server to run itself

Comment: I was thinking this, in that case might just use this https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/sing-app-web-angular-2.0-dashboard-WB0J6BJ85